# Testing 'sandboxed' javascript expression evaluation modules for selection

Tags: javascript, expression, sandbox, evaluation

Are there any existing test libraries out there to test the performance, footprint and security of the many sandboxed Javascript Expression libraries available?

A partial list of the many candidates out there: safely-expressed, sandboxed-javascript-expressions, expression-sandbox, forgood, notevil-esprima4, safevil, pico-sandbox

I'd like to pick one for my project and prefer to run automated testing to aid my selection. Maybe there is a library out there that pen testers use for checking for insecure use of eval() I could use?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I should add that I only need an expression sandbox for JavaScript in the browser.  Not a full isolated Javascript VM.